# How can I associate a "document" with a SharePoint list, and have the workflow wait for the document to be checked in?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, document, versioning

I have a SharePoint list workflow running on the latest/greatest SharePoint OnLine.  I'm using SharePoint Designer 2013.  Unfortunately, PowerApps Flow is not an option.

I'd like to add some new steps to the workflow:

1. The workflow should launch a Process Task to the Sales Rep ("Current Item:Created By") asking him to fill out a "CustomerForm".
2. An MS Word doc, "CustomerForm Template", exists in the Document Library.
    The email that the Process Task sends to the Sales Rep has a link to the template.
3. The Sales Rep needs to complete the template, "Save As" to a new .doc, and forward it to the company's DocuSign team for customer signature.

Q: Is there any way I can facilitate the Sales Rep saving the completed form to the Document Library (instead of "Save As" to a .docx file on his hard drive)?

Q: If so, how can I associate the completed .doc file with that specific workflow's list item?

Q: Are there any SharePoint workflow actions or events I can use to automate some or all of these steps?

Q: Can I somehow leverage SharePoint versioning (e.g. trigger on document check-in to automatically send an e-mail to the DocuSign team)?

Answer (score 1):

Q1: Yes, it is quite easy to do so if the Sales Rep is using Office 365, detailed process [here](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-easily-save-to-sharepoint-from-word-excel-and-powerpoint-also-known-as-save-as/). If you are using earlier version of Office, you may need to check with the some articles.

[Office 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/save-a-file-to-a-sharepoint-library-32204d9f-55ea-4232-a32b-aa7e046afcdd) [Office 2013 and 2016](https://www.sharepointsky.com/save-excel-file-into-sharepoint-online-document-library/)

Q2: The easiest way to do so is using the attachment. You can attach the file to the task in your task list like the screenshot below:
[image]

Q3: You can send a notification email to the sales rep after a Process task is created. Also you can check in/out files with workflow.

Q4: Technically you can do so, just need to create a event receiver for this. Examples you can check:[Start workflow when file is checked in](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59149/start-workflow-when-file-is-checked-in)